# how to detect change in url parameter values on page reload on same page in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am new to jquery i have any issue , i need to perform a logic whenever the url parameter values changes , can you please help me with that

```
my url :

    https://used.rentals.com/Equipment/used?order=price

    expected result :

if there is change in the order value do logic.
```

I have tried  this code but not working

```
  <script>
      var firstTimeUrl = document.URL;
      document.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var currentPageUrl = document.URL;
      var url = new URL(currentPageUrl);
      var isVariantUrl = url.searchParams.get("order");
      currentPageUrl = isVariantUrl ? currentPageUrl :isVariantUrl;
        if(currentPageUrl && firstTimeUrl != currentPageUrl) {
          firstTimeUrl = currentPageUrl;
          console.log('variant_id: '+isVariantUrl+'')
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: If the page is reloaded you cannot detect a change as there is no frame of reference to know what the previous URL was. If the URL is updated during the page lifetime, then you can potentially use [`popState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event), depending on how the URL was updated.

Comment: What is the code/action/event/component that's causing it to change.  I'm assuming it's a third-party element otherwise you'd just call your "change" handler when you change the url.  There may be an event / callback option that you can "hook" into, eg a "sorted" event raised by the component.

Comment: Alternatively, and assuming as above, that it's changed in the page rather than on a new page, you could overload/overwrite the `window.pushState()` method (as a starter).  Depends on how/when it's updated.

Comment: @freedomn it will be on the same page , it refreshes , can you give me code example

Comment: *"it refreshes"* and "*on page reload*" (missed this earlier) means it's probably not on the same *instance of the page*.  In which case, it hasn't "changed" as you have a new instance and the old value no longer exists, it's just as it is - so handle it in [`doc.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: how to handle in doc.ready , can you give me example ?